# How do I make my self bot grab the token from the config file instead of putting the token in the code?

Tags: token, config

`bot.run("TOKEN", bot=False)`

How do I change that to grab the token from the config.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function to read json files:

```
import json

def load_json(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data
```

You can learn more about json [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

Then you can use that in here:

```
bot.run(load_json("path/to/file.json")["token"], bot=False)
```

Your json file should be like this:

```
{
    "token": "yourtoken"
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it man